# I want to print a Rectangle in my DOM by JavaScript by taking a user input, but when I run this code I got 'str' is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I want to create a rectangle whenever somebody click on "try it" button I will ask number of line from user and it will print same line row and column to form a rectangle. But when I ran this code, I will get nothing on my DOM and its says in console that str is not defined at line 27, but I already defined it, don't know where the problem is

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

      <p id="demo"></p>

      <script>
        const myFunction = () => {
          let insertLine = prompt("put the no. of lines Here: ");
          let str = "";
          for (i = 0; i < insertLine; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
              str += "*";
            }
          str += "\n";
        };
        console.log(str);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you define `str` inside `myFunction` but you try to use it outside. console.log and innerHTML assignment should be in the function, not outside.

Answer (score 2):

You try to use the "str" variable outside of it's definition scope :

You defined `str` in `MyFunction` but you use it outside when you try to log it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your problem, but the console.log() and the document.getElementById() should be inside your function. Your for loop also needed changes to print the complete rectangle. Try this code and let me know if it works.

```
    const myFunction = () => {
      let insertLine = prompt("put the no. of lines Here: ");
      let str = "";
      for (i = 0; i < insertLine; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < insertLine; j++) {
          str += "*";
        }
        str += "<br/>";
      }  
      
      console.log(str);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
    };
```